# Pandas read csv file values as text without transforming to float first

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm loading data from a csv file into pandas data frame, the column in the csv file contains these values:

```
1,2,3.4,5,6.2
```

The issue is that int values are changed to floats (I understand that this is because float will be the more general dtype), so it is read as:

```
df
   value
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.4
3    5.0
4    6.2
```

I need to get all the values as they are in the csv file as strings.

I tried using `pd.read_csv('filename.csv',dtype=str)` or `pd.read_csv('filename.csv',dtype=object)` and they result to changing them to floats then str:

```
  value
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.4
3  5.0
4  6.2
```

is there any way to read them as they are? i.e:

```
  value
0     1
1     2
2   3.4
3     5
4   6.2
```

Comment: AFAIK using `pd.read_csv('filename.csv',dtype=str)` will result in data being strings. Isn't that the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

This is my test CSV (untitled.csv):

> a,1
>
> b,2
>
> c,3.4
>
> d,5
>
> e,6.2

With the following code `pd.read_csv('untitled.csv', dtype='str', header=None)`, I obtain:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use

- [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) - Read a comma-separated values (csv) file into DataFrame.
- [`DataFrame.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) - Transpose index and columns.
- [`DataFrame.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) - Alter axes labels.

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# csv file contain single text row value 
csv1 = StringIO("""1,2,3.4,5,6.2""")
# csv1 replace with csv file name eg. 'filename.csv'
df = (pd.read_csv(csv1,dtype=str,header=None)).T.rename(columns={0:'value'})
print(df)
   value
0     1
1     2
2   3.4
3     5
4   6.2


# csv file contain multiple text row value 
csv2 = StringIO("""1
2
3.4
5
6.2""")
# csv2 replace with csv file name eg. 'filename.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(csv2,dtype=str,header=None,names=['value'])
print(df1)
  value
0     1
1     2
2   3.4
3     5
4   6.2
```